# React Native - Share code for different applications

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native application called **A**, now I want create another application very similar to **A**, I only need change some colours the rest of the code is **exactly** the same. One option could be create a new application **B** and copy all the code from **A** and change the hard coded colours, obviously it doesn't look very clever because now I have to maintain two different applications.

There are any way to load the colours information from a *theme* file and then when I start the application determinate what file the application should use?

Comment: Did you get it to work? And did you use different applicationIds?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using product flavors.

Take a look at the docs:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: @Andre Classen did you get it to work?
Everytime I try to build the App with productFlavors I get "Activity class {... / ....MainActivity} does not exist.